# convert String to MD5

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, md5

Ok I am trying to write a basic converter of a string to `md5` hash code but when I run my program I keep getting an error that say's:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Amer CISC\lab4.py", line 30, in <module>
    assertEqual (computeMD5hash("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"),("9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6"))
  File "C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Amer CISC\lab4.py", line 27, in computeMD5hash
    m.update(string)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

My code looks like this:

```
def computeMD5hash(string):
    import hashlib
    from hashlib import md5
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update((string))
    md5string=m.digest()
    return md5string
```

Comment: also, it's good to avoid using 'special words' for not-so-special applications. For example 'string' is the name of a module. Even though it is not an error it is best to avoid ambiguity wherever possible

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As the error suggests, your `string` must be unicode and you have to encode it. Looking at the call you make (from your stack trace):

```
computeMD5hash("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

it looks like you must be running Python 3 where strings are unicode objects. To encode to a byte representation which can then be processed by the hashlib, change this

```
m.update((string))
```

to this (if utf-8 is an appropriate encoding for you to use - it depends how you will be using this):

```
m.update(string.encode('utf-8'))
```

If this is all news to you, you should probably read the excellent [Python 3 Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3.0/howto/unicode.html).

---

Also, while I'm here, your code has some other issues

- some unecessary bits - no need for the `from hashlib import` line or the temporary `md5string`.
- it's bad form to import modules from within a function, so `import hashlib` should be moved to module scope.
- the function is returning the [`digest()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.digest) which is raw binary, and from your stack trace it looks like you're expecting the [`hexdigest()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) instead which is the same thing represented as a hexadecimal string.

To fix and tidy it all up, try this:

```
import hashlib

def computeMD5hash(my_string):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(my_string.encode('utf-8'))
    return m.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 16):

Rather than trying to hash the string, you should hash an encoded byte sequence.  Instead of

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5("fred")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

you should encode it, e.g.:

```
>>> "fred".encode("utf")
b'fred'
>>> hashlib.md5("fred".encode("utf")).hexdigest()
'570a90bfbf8c7eab5dc5d4e26832d5b1'
```

In Python 2 you could get away without doing this, and it led to no end of unnoticed bugs.  Fortunately Python 3 has much saner unicode support, and distinguishes between bytes and strings.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have to encode the string before hashing:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/246026-generating-string-hash-issue/

Answer (score 1):

All of the above answers work fine.
You can also try this, with a function

```
import hashlib

def md5hasher(what_text):       
    return hashlib.md5(what_text.encode("utf")).hexdigest()
```

try it!

```
md5hasher(your_text_to_encrypt)
```

Your output would be with 123456 as your_text_to_encrypt

> "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e"