# MD5 hashing: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, python-3.x, md5, hashlib

I have some code to hash a string in Python 3

```
import hashlib
hobj = hashlib.md5()
```

And when I use the command:

```
hobj.update('test')
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert String to MD5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259691/convert-string-to-md5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encode the string to UTF-8 (for example):

```
hobj.update('test'.encode("UTF-8"))
print(hobj.hexdigest())
```

Output:

```
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

Comment: You are welcome to upvote and/or accept the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer