# How can I implement an algorithm to encode my data into MD5 string in Python?

Tags: java, python

I'm not familiar with Python. I have a java snippet to implement an algorithm to encode my data into MD5 string. I'd like to convert it into Python. My java code is using commons-codec1.9 to encodeBase64.
Anyone can help? Thanks very much.

```
 public static void Main(args){
 String data ="token=cd264af2fbd&app_key=060176144a&client_os_type=4";
 String key = "87483ik98abh";
 String md5EncodedData = getEncodeData(data, key);
```

}

```
private static final String HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA1";
public String getEncodeData(String app_secret, String data){
    try{
        byte[] hmc = calculateRFC2104HMAC(Base64.encodeBase64(data.getBytes()), app_secret);
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(hmc);
        return new String(Hex.encodeHex(thedigest));

    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.print(ex.getMessage().toString());
    }
    return "";
}
public static byte[] calculateRFC2104HMAC(byte[] data, String key)
        throws java.security.SignatureException
{
    try {

        // get an hmac_sha1 key from the raw key bytes
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);

        // get an hmac_sha1 Mac instance and initialize with the signing key
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(signingKey);

        // compute the hmac on input data bytes
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data);
        return rawHmac;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SignatureException("Failed to generate HMAC : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: It might helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259691/convert-string-to-md5

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the hashlib module of python?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib

Answer (score 0):

If you want to efficiently code the MD5 Hashing using python, my github repository would definitely help to understand and interpret the mathematical definitions of MD% in python

[Cryptographic Algoritms Implementation Using Python](https://github.com/harsha0795)

```

def md5(message):

```
message = bytearray(message) #copy our input into a mutable buffer
orig_len_in_bits = (8 * len(message)) & 0xffffffffffffffff
message.append(0x80)
while len(message)%64 != 56:
    message.append(0)
message += orig_len_in_bits.to_bytes(8, byteorder='little')

hash_pieces = init_values[:]

for chunk_ofst in range(0, len(message), 64):
    a, b, c, d = hash_pieces
    chunk = message[chunk_ofst:chunk_ofst+64]
    for i in range(64):
        f = functions[i](b, c, d)
        g = index_functions[i](i)
        to_rotate = a + f + constants[i] + int.from_bytes(chunk[4*g:4*g+4], byteorder='little')
        new_b = (b + left_rotate(to_rotate, rotate_amounts[i])) & 0xFFFFFFFF
        a, b, c, d = d, new_b, b, c
    for i, val in enumerate([a, b, c, d]):
        hash_pieces[i] += val
        hash_pieces[i] &= 0xFFFFFFFF

return sum(x<<(32*i) for i, x in enumerate(hash_pieces)
```

```